# Specify content-type for files in multipart/form-data for Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, mime-types, swagger-codegen

I have implemented endpoint with this signature

```
[HttpPost("Test")]
public IActionResult MyTest([Required] IFormFile pdf, [Required] IFormFile image)
{
    // some stuff...

    return Ok();
}
```

this generates following entry in swagger.json *(the relevant part)*

```
"content": {
    "multipart/form-data": {
        "schema": {
            "required": [
                "image",
                "pdf"
            ],
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "pdf": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "binary"
                },
                "image": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "binary"
                }
            }
        },
        "encoding": {
            "pdf": {
                "style": "form"
            },
            "image": {
                "style": "form"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but, I also need specify encoding, like in [the specs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/multipart-requests/#content-type) (v3). So for my task, that JSON should look like this, I think...

```
"encoding": {
    "pdf": {
        "style": "form",
        "contentType": "application/pdf"
    },
    "image": {
        "style": "form",
        "contentType": "image/png, image/jpeg"
    }
}
```

**But how can I do that from code?** I thought about [SwaggerParameter attribute](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#enrich-parameter-metadata), but it contains only description and required flag...

I'm using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore NuGeT package (version 5.0.0-rc2) on .NET Core 2.2.

Comment: I am having this problem too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [this line](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/60cd697d36771f76a1d16592228fa231a169285f/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen/SwaggerGenerator/SwaggerGenerator.cs#L342), you'll see that encoding is created with only `Style` property, while `ContentType` is not set. What you can do is set this manually by creating custom `Attribute` where you'd define your content type:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter,AllowMultiple = false)]
public class OpenApiEncodingContentTypeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public OpenApiEncodingContentTypeAttribute(string contentType)
    {
        ContentType = contentType;
    }

    public string ContentType { get; }
}
```

and then use that `Attribute` within `IOperationFilter`

```
public class FormContentTypeSchemaOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var contentTypeByParameterName = context.MethodInfo.GetParameters()
            .Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(OpenApiEncodingContentTypeAttribute), true))
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, s => s.GetCustomAttribute<OpenApiEncodingContentTypeAttribute>().ContentType);

        if (contentTypeByParameterName.Any())
        {
            foreach (var requestContent in operation.RequestBody.Content)
            {
                var encodings = requestContent.Value.Encoding;
                foreach (var encoding in encodings)
                {
                    if (contentTypeByParameterName.TryGetValue(encoding.Key, out string value))
                    {
                        encoding.Value.ContentType = value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then just decorate your parameters with this `Attribute`

```
[HttpPost("Test")]
public IActionResult MyTest([Required] [OpenApiEncodingContentType("application/pdf")] IFormFile pdf, [Required] [OpenApiEncodingContentType("image/png, image/jpeg")] IFormFile image)
{
    // some stuff...
    return Ok();
}
```

Also don't forget to define your `IOperationFilter` in `AddSwaggerGen`

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(opts =>
{
    // all other stuff
    opts.OperationFilter<FormContentTypeSchemaOperationFilter>();
})
```

This is what you get

```
"requestBody": {
  "content": {
    "multipart/form-data": {
      "schema": {
        "required": [
          "image",
          "pdf"
        ],
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "pdf": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "binary"
          },
          "image": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "binary"
          }
        }
      },
      "encoding": {
        "pdf": {
          "contentType": "application/pdf",
          "style": "form"
        },
        "image": {
          "contentType": "image/png, image/jpeg",
          "style": "form"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can probably improve `IOperationFilter` with additional checks/null-checks and other stuff that suits your needs, because this is just a basic implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look into ISchemaFilter and the following Issue:

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1148

This might help you to filter for your operation and add the diffrent contentStyles for the same type (IFormInput).

I believe that what you want to achieve is currently only possible with a custom attribute, however there is an active branch for enhanced FormsInput support in active development, maybe you can add a feature request.

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/commits/enhance-support-for-forms